# Scala type dependency in a type safe library

Tags: scala, traits, scala-macros

(Scala 2.11)

Hello,

**Overview**

I'm trying to create a library which has an expandable type system. Because my library is too large and complicated, I created the following example which is completely different but has similar inheritance and dependency structure.

I created a 'cannibals' library. Its purpose is to construct cannibals belonging to different tribes (types) with the following properties:

- **Works** All cannibals have common actions.
- **Works** Each tribe has its own unique possible actions which can happen with/without another cannibal.
- **Works** All cannibals must belong to a tribe. A cannibal can be either 'Normal' or 'Hungry'. Hungry cannibals have extra/other actions than normal cannibals.
- **Works** All cannibals can produce children. A child will maintain the tribe (type) of the cannibal who produced it. A normal cannibal will produce a normal child. A hungry cannibal will produce a hungry child.
- **Does not work** A cannibal can convert to another tribe (but must maintain its hungry/normal status).
- **Does not work** An adopting tribe cannibal can adopt hungry cannibals from other tribes. An adopted cannibal maintains its tribal type. If a hungry cannibal is adopted by a hungry cannibal, then the adopted cannibal remains hungry. If it is adopted by a normal cannibal, then the adopted will become a normal cannibal.

The library has three traits (*AnyCannibalLike*, *AnyNormalCannibalLike*, *AnyHungryCannibalLike*) which all other traits and classes will inherit from. The library also has abstract classes used to create the concrete case classes of the different tribes.
[Please look at the following image to understand the inheritance structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyeie.png).

**Library code + JungleCannibals and UrbanCannibals examples**

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Any cannibal traits and abstract classes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
trait AnyCannibalLike {
  type TBasic <: AnyCannibalLike
  type TNormal <: AnyCannibalLike
  type THungry <: AnyCannibalLike
  type TChild <: AnyCannibalLike

  //name of the cannibal
  protected val _name : String
  def getName() = _name

  //Any cannibal can play with any cannibal
  def playWith(anyCannibal : AnyCannibalLike) : Unit

  //Any cannibal can bring a child of the same tribe into the world.
  //If the cannibal is normal then the child will be normal
  //If the cannibal is hungry then the child will be hungry
  def birthChild(childName : String) : TChild
  protected final def completeNameOfChild(childName : String) = childName + " (child of " + getName() + ")"
}

trait AnyNormalCannibalLike[Basic <: AnyCannibalLike] extends AnyCannibalLike {
  type TBasic = Basic
  type TChild = TNormal
  //How to do this?
  //def changeTo[Basic <: AnyCannibalLike, Normal <: AnyNormalCannibalLike[Basic], Hungry <: AnyHungryCannibalLike[Basic]]() : Normal
}

trait AnyHungryCannibalLike[Basic <: AnyCannibalLike] extends AnyCannibalLike {
  type TBasic = Basic
  type TChild = THungry
  //Any hungry cannibal can eat other cannibals of the same tribe
  def eat(sameCannibal : Basic) : Unit
  //How to do this?
  //def changeTo[Basic <: AnyCannibalLike, Normal <: AnyNormalCannibalLike[Basic], Hungry <: AnyHungryCannibalLike[Basic]]() : Hungry
}

abstract class AnyNormalCannibalA[Basic <: AnyCannibalLike, Normal <: AnyNormalCannibalLike[Basic], Hungry <: AnyHungryCannibalLike[Basic]](name : String) extends AnyNormalCannibalLike[Basic] {
  type TNormal = Normal
  type THungry = Hungry
  protected val _name : String = name
  def playWith(anyCannibal : AnyCannibalLike) : Unit = {
    println(getName() + " playing with " + anyCannibal.getName())
  }
}

abstract class AnyHungryCannibalA[Basic <: AnyCannibalLike, Normal <: AnyNormalCannibalLike[Basic], Hungry <: AnyHungryCannibalLike[Basic]](name : String, eatingTool : String) extends AnyHungryCannibalLike[Basic] {
  type TNormal = Normal
  type THungry = Hungry
  protected val _name : String = name
  def playWith(anyCannibal : AnyCannibalLike) : Unit = {
    println(getName() + " playing hungrily with " + anyCannibal.getName())
  }
  def eat(sameCannibal : Basic) : Unit = {
    println(getName() + " eating " + sameCannibal.asInstanceOf[AnyCannibalLike].getName() + " using " + eatingTool)
  }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Jungle cannibal traits and case classes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
trait JungleCannibalLike extends AnyCannibalLike {
  //Jungle cannibals can hunt with other jungle cannibals
  def huntWith(jungleCannibal : JungleCannibalLike) : Unit = {
    println(getName() + " hunting with " + jungleCannibal.getName())
  }
}

trait JungleNormalCannibalLike extends AnyNormalCannibalLike[JungleCannibalLike] with JungleCannibalLike

trait JungleHungryCannibalLike extends AnyHungryCannibalLike[JungleCannibalLike] with JungleCannibalLike {
  //Jungle cannibals can hunt with and then eat other jungle cannibals
  def huntAndEat(jungleCannibal: JungleCannibalLike) : Unit = {
    huntWith(jungleCannibal)
    eat(jungleCannibal)
  }
}

case class JungleNormalCannibal(name : String) extends AnyNormalCannibalA[JungleCannibalLike, JungleNormalCannibalLike, JungleHungryCannibalLike](name) with JungleNormalCannibalLike {
  def birthChild(childName : String) : TChild = JungleNormalCannibal(completeNameOfChild(childName))
}
case class JungleHungryCannibal(name : String) extends AnyHungryCannibalA[JungleCannibalLike, JungleNormalCannibalLike, JungleHungryCannibalLike](name,"hands") with JungleHungryCannibalLike {
  def birthChild(childName : String) : TChild = JungleHungryCannibal(completeNameOfChild(childName))
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Urban cannibal traits and case classes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
trait UrbanCannibalLike extends AnyCannibalLike {
  //Urban cannibals can read with other urban cannibals
  def readWith(urbanCannibal : UrbanCannibalLike) : Unit = {
    println(getName() + " reading with " + urbanCannibal.getName())
  }
}

trait UrbanNormalCannibalLike extends AnyNormalCannibalLike[UrbanCannibalLike] with UrbanCannibalLike

trait UrbanHungryCannibalLike extends AnyHungryCannibalLike[UrbanCannibalLike] with UrbanCannibalLike {
  //Urban cannibals can read with and then eat other urban cannibals
  def readAndEat(urbanCannibal: UrbanCannibalLike) : Unit = {
    readWith(urbanCannibal)
    eat(urbanCannibal)
  }
}

case class UrbanNormalCannibal(name : String) extends AnyNormalCannibalA[UrbanCannibalLike, UrbanNormalCannibalLike, UrbanHungryCannibalLike](name) with UrbanNormalCannibalLike {
  def birthChild(childName : String) : TChild = UrbanNormalCannibal(completeNameOfChild(childName))
}
case class UrbanHungryCannibal(name : String) extends AnyHungryCannibalA[UrbanCannibalLike, UrbanNormalCannibalLike, UrbanHungryCannibalLike](name,"fork") with UrbanHungryCannibalLike {
  def birthChild(childName : String) : TChild = UrbanHungryCannibal(completeNameOfChild(childName))
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Adopting cannibal traits and case classes
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
trait AdoptingCannibalLike extends AnyCannibalLike {
  //Adopting cannibals can adopt any hungry cannibal.
  //If the adopter is hungry then the returned adopted should keep its type as is.
  //If the adopter is not hungry then the returned adopted is the same type but not hungry.
  //how to do this?
  //def adoptHungryCannibal(hungryCannibal : AnyHungryCannibalLike[_]) : hungryCannibal.type = hungryCannibal
  //val ajhc = adoptHungryCannibal(JungleHungryCannibal("jhc"))
}

trait AdoptingNormalCannibalLike extends AnyNormalCannibalLike[AdoptingCannibalLike] with AdoptingCannibalLike
trait AdoptingHungryCannibalLike extends AnyHungryCannibalLike[AdoptingCannibalLike] with AdoptingCannibalLike

case class AdoptingNormalCannibal(name : String) extends AnyNormalCannibalA[AdoptingCannibalLike, AdoptingNormalCannibalLike, AdoptingHungryCannibalLike](name) with AdoptingNormalCannibalLike {
  def birthChild(childName : String) : TChild = AdoptingNormalCannibal(completeNameOfChild(childName))
}
case class AdoptingHungryCannibal(name : String) extends AnyHungryCannibalA[AdoptingCannibalLike, AdoptingNormalCannibalLike, AdoptingHungryCannibalLike](name,"my kids") with AdoptingHungryCannibalLike {
  def birthChild(childName : String) : TChild = AdoptingHungryCannibal(completeNameOfChild(childName))
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

**Test code**

```
val jnc = JungleNormalCannibal("jnc")
val jhc = JungleHungryCannibal("jhc")
val unc = UrbanNormalCannibal("unc")
val uhc = UrbanHungryCannibal("uhc")

val cjnc = jnc.birthChild("cjnc")
val cjhc = jhc.birthChild("cjhc")

//Must execute
jnc.playWith(jnc)
jnc.playWith(unc)
jhc.eat(jnc)
uhc.eat(unc)
jnc.huntWith(jhc)
jhc.huntWith(jnc)
cjnc.huntWith(jhc)
cjhc.huntAndEat(jnc)

//Must produce compilation errors
jnc.huntWith(unc)
jnc.eat(jnc)
cjnc.huntWith(unc)
cjnc.eat(jnc)
```

**Problems**

1. Unable to implement changeTo[,,] which creates a new cannibal with the same name but different type (I'm guessing both implicits and macros need to be utilized in-order to achieve this, but I have no idea how.
2. Unable to implement adoptHungryCannibal. Similar problem to #1?
3. The code seems too verbose. To create a new tribe we repeat a lot of code. Any suggestions how to simplify it (Macros, dependency injections)?

**Notes**

Since I am fairly new to Scala, I may not have written conventional code. Please point out mistakes if you see any.